# Pillow crop images keeping the ratio having a max width and max height

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to crop something using Pillow, by keeping the ratio, and max_height or max_width.

Some images can have a bigger width or a bigger height.

I tried:

```
        image_clone = image.copy()
        width_percent = (size['width'] / float(image_clone.size[0]))
        height = int((float(image_clone.size[1]) * float(width_percent)))
        image_clone.thumbnail((size['width'], height), Image.LANCZOS)
```

Doesn't work well for images that have a bigger width because the height will be small, and the image not very visible.

Comment: Looks like you need an `if` to pick which of width_percent or height_percent is better and use that one to scale the other dimension.

Comment: @DanD. ok, but what should be the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unclear. I had see this code before to scale down a image so that it fit in a box. The condition is to pick the larger as that works for portrait and landscape as well as for square sizes:

```
    image_clone = image.copy()
    width_percent = (size['width'] / float(image_clone.size[0]))
    height_percent = (size['height'] / float(image_clone.size[1]))
    if width_percent > height_percent:
        height = int((float(image_clone.size[1]) * float(width_percent)))
        image_clone.thumbnail((size['width'], height), Image.LANCZOS)
    else:
        width = int((float(image_clone.size[0]) * float(height_percent)))
        image_clone.thumbnail((width, size['height']), Image.LANCZOS)
```

Untested.

Comment: thanks, this works if the box is square, I had to make some changes to it, if is not square